# 'ufw status' vs 'service ufw status'

Tags: 16.04, ufw

`service ufw status` says `ufw` is active, while `ufw status` says `ufw` is "inactive". Why are `ufw` status results different? If each result has different meaning, please explain each meaning and difference.

[image: ufw status check result]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`service ufw status` (Active) states that the service of `ufw` (its daemon) is running in the background and is ready to work. in newer versions of Ubuntu
 its equivalent is:

```
systemctl status ufw
```

`ufw status` talks about the `ufw` itself, it says what the daemon (if it is active) is doing. By saying it's "inactive",  it means firewall does nothing (however it's still living in the background and is ready to be enabled).

- Service: Active, UFW: Active: I'm here and I'm doing my job.
- Service: Active, UFW: Inactive: I'm here and I'm doing nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your easy and good explanation. could you tell me one more thing? you said 'UFW: Inactive = I'm doing nothing'. Is it caused because there are not any rule added or because just ufw is turned off?

Comment: I think because it's not enabled, use `sudo ufw enable` to enable it. after that it is doing it's job however you still didn't told it to do what (there is no rule) so after enabling it you should add some rule too.